# Comment Form Missing

Tags: comments

I'm baffled by this issue on my new site. I have double checked permissions to verify that authenticated users can post so I'm just getting that out of the way first off.

However, what is odd is that each node (where I rely off of the default Drupal node template, and those in which I have created a custom template) has a "Login or Register to Post Comments" div and appropriate links, however, when I login as a test user, there is no comment form.

I'm not sure where to go from here, as even my Admin account cannot see the comments form.

EDIT-----------

Also, all comment settings are set to "Open" for all content types and individual content postings.

EDIT-----------

I have rebuilt the permissions as well, just in case. Nothing has changed.

EDIT-----------

I happened to remember that I had previously posted a test comment on one of the pages, and now I can't see that comment, even if I go through the admin panels. I can see that there is a comment, but I cannot see the comment itself.

Comment: Perhaps your template file is not printing the comments. Check your **node.tpl.php** file, located in **/sites/all/themes/YourTheme/templates** folder. It should have `<?php print render($content['comments']); ?>` in there. Also, check any other node template if have others. Ex: **node--articles.tpl.php**

Comment: I just double checked all of them, and each one has the exact code you mentioned, the only time it is referenced to elsewhere in the template file is here `<?php
    // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
    hide($content['comments']);
    hide($content['links']);
  ?>` otherwise, there is nothing else. Should I remove this hide now code?

Comment: mine also has the `hide($content['comments']); hide($content['links']); ` so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: In your Content Type >> Manage Display >> on the top right there is a Comments link, click on it. Are your comments visible?

Comment: Do you mean "Comment Display"?, if not there is nothing besides "Comment Fields" in the top right. If you are referring to "Comment Display", it is showing that the comments are visible and are not hidden. And I'm sorry if I'm drawing out things, I just want to make sure I don't make a stupid mistake on my end.

Comment: no problem, yes I was referring to Comment Display.

Comment: Hummm.. try switching to the default drupal theme and see if the comments show.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, and after I reverted to the default theme, I cleared the cache, ran cron, still nothing.

Comment: `when I login as a test user, there is no comment form.` what about when you're (user/1) admin, can you see the comment form?

Comment: It still shows nothing, the only time I can see that there are comments are when I go to "admin/content/comment", but when I click the comment, it goes to the right page, however the actual comment is nowhere to be found...

Comment: Are you using the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module?

Comment: Yes, I just checked, I think it was needed to an Organic Group example.

Comment: *for an organic group example, sorry

Comment: then check your panel, perhaps you did not add comments to your panel.

Comment: Well I have not enabled any of the panels, (which makes me wonder why I needed panels in the first place), so I am not sure where I have to enable it specifically for comments. If would be better, should I just disable panels altogether?

Comment: yes try disabling Panels to see what happens, also if you don't plan on using Panels, then there is no point in having it enabled.

Comment: That was it. I don't know how panels messed with it but apparently with absolutely no panels enabled - it managed to hide my comments. So thank you for getting me through this.

Comment: no problem, glad you got this resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was to Disable Panels

or you could add the comment form to the Panel.